# Centralized leaderboard for Android

Tags: android, leaderboard

Does Android provide a centralized leaderboard feature like Apple's Game Center leaderboard? (so that there is no need to use 3rd party services like OpenFeint)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such feature like centralized leaderboard or other statistics. You should Use third party libraries like Swarm or OpenFeint.

Answer (score 1):

No, android does not have similar service.
Use a third-party, like a ScoreLoop, Crystal or OpenFeint(seems someone bought it and it is now called GREE)

Comment: Off topic, but GREE bought Openfeint? Very cool, GREE has a good record, and they are *everywhere* in Japan.

Comment: It seems that it is.
On the official website they say that you can not register a new game on Openfeint SDK and should be used GREE.